# How to create link with a random agent in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have some agents on lattice. If we consider an agent $i$, then I will assign different probabilities to all remaining agents  depending on agent $i$ characteristics. Now my goal is to pick one of agent $j$ from the remaining agents with specified probabilities and create link from agent $i$ to agent $j$. This I have to do for all agents lattice. [ each time the probabilities change according to the different agents $i$]
Can some one help how to implement this on netlogo.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not constrain the problem more, computation will get expensive.  Here is the basic idea, assuming you have an `assign-probabilities` reporter:

```
to form-links ;;turtle proc
  let %others [self] of other turtles ;;list of other turltes
  let %p assign-probabilities %others
  let %idx random-index %p
  create-link-with item %idx %others
end

to-report random-index [#p] ;;input probability dist as list
  let %draw random-float 1
  let %cum-p item 0 #p
  let %ct 0
  while [%draw > %cum-p] [
    set %ct (%ct + 1)
    set %cum-p (%cum-p + item %ct #p)   
  ]
  report %ct
end
```

Here are some things that can help make the computations less costly. If turtles are not created or dying, you can compute the others only once during setup (and set as a turtle attribute).  If the probabilities do not change over time, you can do the same with the probabilities.  In the latter case, you will then probably want to compute the cumulative probabilities (once), and use a bisection algorithm to produce the random index.

Comment: see also Lottery Example, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library. and see also `rnd:weighted-one-of` at https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension